# what is the fastest way to compare a pair struct

Tags: c++, optimization, struct

My project find a performance bottleneck at a struct compare.
The struct just a pair of int

```
struct Edge
{
int node_a;
int node_b;
};
```

and the compare function looks like below:

```
// my wrong code: do not see it, it will leads to UB
bool edgeCompare(const Edge &edge_a, const Edge &edge_b)
{
     if (edge_a.node_a < edge_b.node_a)
     {
         return true;
     }
     if (edge_a.node_b < edge_b.node_b)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

```
// correct code from @paxdiablo
bool edgeCompare(const Edge &edge_a, const Edge &edge_b) {
    if (edge_a.node_a < edge_b.node_a) return true;
    if (edge_a.node_a > edge_b.node_a) return false;

    // Only now are the node_a values equal, check node_b.

    return edge_a->node_b < edge_b->node_b;
}
```

My problem is how to do optimzation at the compare function to get the performance boot as much as possible?

May be some technique can be used like: reduce branch prediction failed or using bit calculation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are the functions supposed to model `<`? Because they don't do that correctly. I suggest you provide a [repro] for the performance issue. There isn't really much to optimize by hand here that the compiler couldn't do itself.

Comment: yes, I want to model the operator `<`.

Comment: How did you determine that that is the core issue? For example, it could be the number of calls to the function rather than the function itself that is a problem. In that case it would be better to look at the algorithm to determine whether the number of calls can be reduced.

Comment: There is a std::list<Edge> sort in my project. and the sort is proved to be the bottleneck. I already using the `std::sort`, and the `std::sort` using the compare function shown above. Thus the compare function is proved the bottleneck.

Comment: @XuHui Then your program has undefined behavior and talking about performance doesn't make any sense in the first place, because you are violating `std::sort`'s requirements on the comparator.

Comment: @walnut oh, you are right, it is a bug... I want first compare a, then compare b. paxdiablo in answer said what acutually in my mind.

Comment: What kaylum said. There's no way the function itself is a bottleneck for performance. It's more likely it's being called too many times.  Perhaps too much sorting and re-sorting?  I dunno, because I don't know what your program does.

Comment: the `std::sort` just be called once.

Comment: If your `Edge` is just a pair of `int`, consider using `std::pair`: `typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;` If you don't want to do that, consider using `std:tie` to do lexicographical compare: `return std::tie(edge_a.node_a, edge_b.node_b) < std::tie(edge_b.node_a, edge_b.node_b);`

Comment: It there any better using `std::pair` compared with the naive struct `Edge`? It can be seen from `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/` that the `std::lexicographical compare` just like the plan given by paxdiabio

Comment: @XuHui when I tested it `std::tie` and `std::pair` seemed to optimise to the pretty much the same as paxdiablo's option. I commented on his answer a (_very slightly_) faster alternative, but there's probably not a lot in it, depending on the compiler.

Comment: @XuHui As an alternative, you could try using `std::vector` instead of `std::list` and seeing if that gives you a speedup: I wouldn't be surprised, due to its improved cache locality. (It can also be used with `std::sort` legally, unlike `std::list`.)

Comment: `std::vector` and the `cache locality` is a greate hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your logic is wrong for a start. Generally, you should hold off worrying about performance until the correctness of your code has been established.

Assuming `node_a` is the more important bit, you should be checking for it *fully* before moving on to `node_b`<sup>(a)</sup>. In other words, something like:

```
bool edgeCompare(const Edge &edge_a, const Edge &edge_b) {
    if (edge_a.node_a < edge_b.node_a) return true;
    if (edge_a.node_a > edge_b.node_a) return false; // need this as well.

    // Only now are the node_a values equal, so check node_b.

    return edge_a->node_b < edge_b->node_b;
}
```

Another possibility is the slightly more succinct:

```
bool edgeCompare(const Edge &edge_a, const Edge &edge_b) {
    // Use node_a if they're different, node_b otherwise.

    if (edge_a.node_a != edge_b.node_a) return
        return edge_a->node_a < edge_b->node_a;

    return edge_a->node_b < edge_b->node_b;
}
```

Those both give you smaller code due to the simplifications, but it may not *necessarily* be faster, it depends on how well your compiler optimised that original `if`.

To be honest, I'm not sure you'll *get* it much faster than that, you're already passing `const` references so that should minimise the amount of stuff pushed on the stack.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is *especially* true if you're using the comparison in a sort function since, otherwise, it may violate the constraints needed for the sort.

Specifically, the constraint that, if `a < b` is true, `a >= b` *must* be false. Without that, sorts tend not to work properly, and may well end up mindlessly swapping the order of things over and over again.

For example, if you have two elements of the form `{node_a, node_b}`, and they are `{1, 7}` and `{2, 5}`, your code as posted, which is effectively:

```
if (edge_a.node_a < edge_b.node_a) return true; // 1
if (edge_a.node_b < edge_b.node_b) return true; // 2
return false;                                   // 3
```

will return true for either being checked against the other:

```
{1, 7} < {2, 5} because 1 < 2 (case 1 above)
{2, 5} < {1, 7} because 2 < 1 is false but 5 < 7 (case 2 above)
```

This could *possibly* be the issue you have with performance if the `sort` function you're using is doing too much work because the constraints have been violated.

Comment: You are right, my code have the bug... I actually want first compare A then compare B as shown in your code. Is there any technique to reduce branch prediction failed? Or using bit compare can acclerate the code?

Comment: It seems that testing `edge_a.node_a != edge_b.node_a` first optimises slightly better with current compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/YP5QZm